# UnsupportedClassVersionError on hadoop with no apparent change of version

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, version

I'm running a hadoop job on my university cluster, which is failing with the following error:

```
hadoop jar target/SpamClassifier-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar <args>
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: infolab/social/spam/FeatureApp : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:205)
```

I've done a bit of reading, and it looks like this can be because the jar is compiled with a version of java that is different to the runtime version.  I tried building on the hadoop master itself (because I enjoy the luxury of permissive shell access to the machine), but it was to no avail.

*Java version:*

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

*Maven version:*

```
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 09:22:22-0600)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.1.1
Java version: 1.7.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-431.5.1.el6.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

*Hadoop version (Hortonworks):*

```
$ hadoop version
Hadoop 2.2.0.2.0.6.0-102
Subversion git@github.com:hortonworks/hadoop.git -r 02ad68f19849a0a986dac36b705491f6791f9179
Compiled by jenkins on 2014-01-21T00:56Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 66f6c486e27479105979740178fbf0
This command was run using /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.2.0.2.0.6.0-102.jar
```

*I am building all of this with maven, and below is the excerpt from my `pom.xml` that specifies java versioning:*

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I really at a loss.  Could it be that maven is compiling using a different version of java for some reason?  I didn't think we even had a different version installed.

Comment: are you sure you are launching it in 1.7.0_45 and you are compiling it in what version ? `mvn --version`

Comment: Good idea, but I'm afraid it's the same.  I've updated my question to include this.

Comment: _SpamClassifier-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar_ is compiled by maven right ? and what is runtime can you try checking runtime version, I still doubt its not same

Comment: It was indeed built with maven.  I don't quite know what runtime version you mean beyond java -version.  Could you elaborate on that and how to check it?

Comment: how do you run that jar ?

Comment: hadoop jar <jar> is the one throwing the error. java -jar <jar> seems to not throw the error.

Comment: not sure how hadoop choose which java to use, can you specify/verify somewhere in its configuraiton file that it uses atleast 1.7

Comment: Ah.  That's the $100 question isn't it.  Where the heck I am configuring hadoop to user 1.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for the help.  The source of the problem was the hadoop configuration, which was overriding my `JAVA_HOME`.  Hadoop configures a custom environment in its `hadoop-env.sh` configuration file.  Mine had been improperly configured with the line:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk64/jdk1.6.0_31
```

This was a result of our using the Hortonworks hadoop suite, which utilizes Ambari and sets up an independent jdk distribution on initial setup.  After upgrading our version of hortonworks and reconfiguring it, our mapreduce jobs are functioning correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have more than one version of **java** installed or some version previously installed on your system and the other one comes with **hadoop** if any.

You are compiling with one and launching with other.

Copy the contents of the environmental variable `PATH` settings to a text and check the locations for the installed versions on the `PATH`. If so, remove one of them and save the `PATH`.

You could also check your **maven** settings, where it should clearly show set `JAVA_HOME`

You could also:

1. Remove automatic build
2. Clean project
3. Build with maven: maven ->  build

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I have double checked, and can find only one copy of java installed on the system.  It is pointed to by both JAVA_HOME and the path.  I have also been manually building with `mvn clean package` this whole time.

Comment: look at this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0

Comment: Thanks @GingerHead, I've seen that before and understand that there is a version difference, but I haven't found anything in that thread that is relevant to a case where version numbers seem to match.

Comment: Also, using just a `find / -name java` I've been able to identify a java executable under `/usr/jdk64/jdk1.6.0_31/bin/java`.  So now I just need to figure out what's been configured to run it.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: SpamClassifier-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Comment: I don't think so.  I unzipped that jar, and can confirm that all the class files are specified as `compiled Java class data, version 51.0`, which of course corresponds to v1.7

Comment: Note, the MANIFEST.MF also has the entry `Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_45`.  Is there somewhere else I should be looking?

Comment: what about hadoop, what version is it using?